# Check if smart contract function exists from code and then call it

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, nodejs, contract-debugging

I'm getting the code of a smart contract by using

```
web3.eth.getCode(contract_address)
```

I want to call certain functions that I'm fairly certain exist on that contract, however I don't know the signatures of every single function in the contract. How would I first check that the function exists?
Assuming the function exists, would it be possible to just decode that function and then call it? Otherwise, how would I decode the whole contract including the functions I don't know in order to get the abi and create the web3 contract onject?

Comment: For some contracts [EIP-165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165) will work. In general it is not possible: 1/ If the contract is a proxy the bytecode won't contain the executable functions. 2/ You could try calling the function. 3/ reverse engineering the bytecode to discover the signatures and a signatures database.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111409/check-for-interface-superset/111416#111416

Comment: Nope. You have to have the ABI.